# Sum of certain integers $a$ where $a^6$ does not divide $6^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the sum of all positive integers $a=2^n3^m$ where $n$ and $m$ are non-negative integers, for which $a^6$ is not a divisor of $6^a$.

Comment: dont it would be infinity?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: It looks like there are only finitely many, since eventually $2^a,3^a$ dominate $6n,6m$ respectively.

Comment: ok we can have such kind of situation $a^6=2^{6*n}*3^{6*m}$ and  $6^a=6^{{2^n}*3^{m}}$

Answer (score 1):

We can write $a^6\mid6^a$ as
$$2^{6n}3^{6m}\mid 2^{2^n3^m}3^{2^n3^m}\ .$$
You want all $m,n$ for which this is **not** true.  So you need
$$6n>2^n3^m\quad\hbox{or}\quad 6m>2^n3^m\ .$$
If $m=0$ we get $n=1,2,3,4$.  If $m=1$ we get $n=0$.  If $m=2$ we get $n=0$.  If $m\ge3$ we get no solution.

Comment: You can include $n=0$ with the $m=0$ cases.

Comment: If $n=m=0$ then the divisibility condition is true, so we don't want this case.

Comment: So right, my mistake.